# How to open windows explorer on selected resource in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was looking for a small plugin for Eclipse that would allow to open windows explorer on currently selected resource from Package Explorer tree.

I know that Aptana Studio provides this functionality via context menu on the resource, but it has tons of other stuff that I am not interested to.

Are there other solutions?

Comment: Alt Shift W (Or right click from Project Explorer to get to 'Show in' context menu). Then System Explorer. (It's like this in Spring Tool Suite 4 based on Eclipse Java Development Tools Version: 3.18.100.v20190916-1045)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I use this plugin, it seems ok

New Eclipse Update Link
https://fabioz.github.com/startexplorer/update/

Old link for reference

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/startexplorer/*
- http://basti1302.github.com/startexplorer/update/

Comment: Nice plugin! I think Eclipse should definitely include this handy tool in their standard release.

Comment: Ok, the license that came up on the install for that made me seriously laugh out loud and the desire to share with co-workers.

Comment: Great plugin - does exactly what I wanted (...apart from the swearing in the licence, which made me wonder if it was legit!)

Comment: This plugin installed for me on Eclipse Indigo but the context menu actions never ever appeared, even after restarting Eclipse twice. Anyone else experience this problem?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher, in the Package Explorer, right click some file/directory/folder. In the context menu, select *Show In -> System Explorer*. This should open up Windows Explorer.

Comment: System explorer not an option, the installation must have failed for me. Thanks anyway for the help @Abdull

Comment: The latest version 1.7.0 works in Eclipse 4.5.1 Mars.1. Thanks.

Comment: @JaySnayder I reinstalled the plugin after seeing your comment. But I don't see anything special except that it is not signed.

Answer (score 61):

In [Eclipse Luna](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.4/eclipse-news-part1.php) and later select a resource, then:

<kbd>Alt + shift + W</kbd> *> System Explorer*

or

*Right click > Show In > System Explorer*

The exact command that should be executed to open the *System Explorer* can be configured here:

*Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Command for launching system explorer*

Comment: The command that's there by default (dbus-send ...) fails on CentOS 6 and CentOS 7. I can change it to 'nautilus "${selected_resource_parent_loc}"' and that works. But I'm creating an RCP app, and I don't want my users to have to manually do this. Does anyone know either why dbus-send fails, or what the preference key is for this so I can change it programmatically?

Comment: FYI more info here: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-9.htm&cp=0_4_1_52, which I got from the bug report here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442562

Comment: Found the pref key with plug-in spy. Details in a separate answer from me

Answer (score 23):

Actually you can do that through the built in External tool manager.
Here are the instructions : http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t77655.html
I'm trying to get it work with Nautilus. However it works under Windows as I tried it.

Comment: Great, works in Windows! No need to install an external plugin.

Comment: This works for me, but is there anyway to then access the newly created program via the context menu for the selected resource?  That would be ideal.

Comment: Works great! did the same config for my Python editor

Answer (score 19):

StartExplorer doesn't work under my Ubuntu, but ExploreFS works. You can find it here:

http://junginger.biz/eclipse/

It supports Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux.

Comment: I'm using eclipse juno and startexplorer 1.5.1 works for me under Ubuntu 12 now

Answer (score 4):

Download OpenExplorer jar file. I am using OpenExplorer_1.5.0.v201108051513.jar downloaded from https://github.com/samsonw/OpenExplorer/archives/master.

Copy this into your eclipse/plugins folder and restart Eclipse. This comes in handy. I would recommend eclipse users having this.

Answer (score 2):

[Eclipse Explorer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-explorer) is an eclipse plugin helping you to open the folder or select resource in explorer quickly. It supports key assist, can open common resource and all java element location, even .jar in library.

Advance feature:

- Support all Java element explorer
- Support key assitant (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> )
- Support Windows and Linux platform
- Support auto selecting file(Windows only)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to open the directory in *Windows Explorer* is to select the file in your Project Explorer and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> and press <kbd>X</kbd>  .

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Plug-In project using Eclipse PDE. Hook your bundle's Activator class into the Common Navigator API to receive selections for `IResource`. For each `IResource` selected, use the [FileLocator](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/FileLocator.html) to get a file URI, with which you can construct a `java.io.File` object. This can then be opened in the operating system's native file explorer using **Java 6 Desktop integration**:

```
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        desktop.open(new File("C:/"));
    }
```

Comment: I would prefer to have this command available in the context menu. What are the relevant interfaces for that?

Answer (score 1):

```
open explorer in eclipse
    - in eclipse -> external tools configurations
    - in program tree -> new
        name: OpenExplore
        localtion: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
        Arguments: /select,${selected_resource_loc}\
```

Answer (score 0):

The command configured by default on a Linux platform (dbus-send ...) fails on CentOS 6 and CentOS 7. Changing it to `nautilus "${selected_resource_parent_loc}"` makes it work. I got this info from this [documentation page](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-9.htm&cp=0_4_1_52), which I got from [this bug report](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442562).

I'm creating an RCP app, and I don't want my users to have to manually change this setting. Using plug-in spy I found the relevant preference store and key. So this non-API call will set the preference programmatically:

```java
    IDEWorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().setValue(IDEInternalPreferences.WORKBENCH_SYSTEM_EXPLORER,
"nautilus \"${selected_resource_parent_loc}\"");
```

With newer versions of nautilus you can specify `${selected_resource_loc}` instead, in which case it opens the parent folder with the specified resource selected. I observed this with nautilus v 3.14, but version 2.28 throws an error is the resource is not a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I use **EasyShell plugin** for Eclipse, it has that functionality and more.

Have a look at that:

https://anb0s.github.io/EasyShell/