# Open directory containing a source file via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tortoisesvn, subclipse

In Visual Studio, or MyEclipse, you have a button which is able to locate a source file on disk, and open the containing directory in Windows explorer.

This is useful, for example, to browse images, or to use an other tool when a conflict occurs in CVS or SVN.

What would be the way to do it in Eclipse with a free plugin, or without any plugin ?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672655/how-to-open-windows-explorer-on-selected-resource-in-eclipse/9038952

Comment: @MuhammadAnnaqeeb This thread exactly works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it :

"In eclipse, it is common requirement to open the folder containing source file but there is no direct method to do that like in Visual studio of Microsoft."

http://shivasoft.in/blog/others/tips/locate-source-file-on-local-disc-in-eclipse-external-tool/

Answer (score 5):

An actual plugin can be found at http://blog.samsonis.me/2009/02/open-explorer-plugin-for-eclipse/

And version 1.5 can be found here http://blog.samsonis.me/2011/08/openexplorer-eclipse-plugin-1-5-0/

Comment: Thank you. this is the best solution, works on eclipse 4.3.2 .

Comment: new link for version 1.5 is http://cloud.github.com/downloads/samsonw/OpenExplorer/OpenExplorer_1.5.0.v201108051513.jar

Comment: Didn't seem to work in Eclipse CDT Kepler for me. Tried putting the jar in both the plugins and dropins directories, and trying to add via Help->Install New Software, but nothing worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with Eclipse 4.5.1 Mars.1

Answer (score 4):

One that I've since upgraded to & find more useful

http://basti1302.github.io/startexplorer/

Comment: For Windows users definitely the best.

Answer (score 4):

I always do this:
right click on file/folder, `show in...`, `system explorer`. Done.

I guess we don't need a plugin to do that, or I am misunderstanding the question?? I am using Luna 4.4.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: Well, I just found that was new, and I am having issues in Luna and they are suggesting me to use Mars, the newest version...how fast...

Answer (score 1):

On Mac you can follow this steps to add it without a plug-in:

1. Click the disclosure icon to the right of the External Tools icon:
   [image: External Tools]
2. Select External Tools Configuration:
   [image: External Tools Pop Up menu]
3. The External Tools Configuration window will appear. Select Programs and then click New Launch Configuration:
   [image: External Tools Configuration Window]
4. This will create a new launch configuration. Enter a name of the configuration in the name field:
   [image: Launch Configuration Field]
5. In the Location field enter the path to the Open Finder, "***/usr/bin/open***" without quotes:
   [image: Location field value]
6. In the Arguments field enter the following argument, ***"${container_loc}"*** with quotes:
   [image: Arguments field value]
7. Click Apply. It should look like the following:
   [image: External Tools Configuration Window filled in]
8. Switch to the build tab and deselect Build before launch:
   [image]
9. Switch to the Common tab and select the External Tools checkbox in Favorites. Click Apply again and close out of the window.
   [image: External Configurations Window Commons Tab]

You are done. Now to use:

1. Select a file or folder in Eclipse Package Explorer.
2. Click the disclosure icon to the right of the External Tools icon:
   [image: External Tools]
3. Select the Open Containing Folder from the drop down menu:
   [image: Open Containing Folder]

You're file or folder should open in Finder.

PRO TIP: After you use the external tool once you can click the External Tools icon again and it will run the last used external tool. In other words, you won't need to select it from the pop up menu each time.

Comment: +1 This answer works well on Windows, too. Though unfortunately, there's no shortcut key for binding an external tool. But it is already fairly good.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look up the source directory by right clicking on the project, going to properties, and looking at "Location: ... "

Comment: Why the downvote? It's not fancy, not best(in newer version), but works under any condition, compatible in all version and platforms.

Comment: It does work. But OP apparently wants something more convenient. +1 for encouragement.