# How to install start Explorer plugin for myEclispe?

Tags: myeclipse

I found that in eclipse this can be done like given here.
[How to open windows explorer on selected resource in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672655/how-to-open-windows-explorer-on-selected-resource-in-eclipse)

How to install this plugin  for myEclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is already in MyEclipse. Right click on the resource (in Package Explorer, Navigator and so on) then select MyEclipse->Open in Explorer.